# Creating a form from a WinForms Control hosted within WPF -- Owner is not set

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

## Scenario

I have the following scenario (I've stripped it down to a sample application):

- A WPF application with a window (**MainWindow**) hosting a WinForms UserControl (**UserControl1**).

  - The control is added dynamically in the code behind to a `WindowsFormsHost`
- **UserControl1** has a button which opens a form (**Form1**)

  - It uses `form1.Show(this)`.

Problem is:

- **Form1**'s `.Owner` property is null.

  - In the real application, some work is done involving the `.Owner` property which means I can't just ignore this problem.  Ideally, of course, there wouldn't be any dependancy here.
  - In the real application, I don't have control over the WinForms side of this code.  Our WPF application is hosting another team's WinForms control.
  - Notes:

    - When I use a WinForms host instead, the `.Owner` property is set correctly.
    - **UserControl1** is hosted fine in all other ways -- in the real application everything else works fine, it's just that the form opened *by* the user control doesn't have a proper owner.

I can understand why there's a problem here, but I'm hoping the answer to my next question might be 'yes'!

**Is there anything I can do to get this to work by making changes on the WPF side of the equation?**

Failing that, could anything be done on the WinForms side? (it's not beyond the realms of possibility that I could get some changes implemented there...)

## Sample Code

Here's the code in my sample app.  First the WPF side:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btnAdd" Click="btnAdd_Click" Content="Add Winform"/>

        <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" Name="host" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WindowsFormsHost host;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        WindowsFormsHost.EnableWindowsFormsInterop();
        this.host.Child = uc1;

    }
}
```

And now the WinForms side...

**UserControl1** is just a user control with a button and a label on it.  Here's the code:

```cs
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show(this);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            this.label1.Text = "this: " + this + Environment.NewLine + "parent: " + this.Parent + Environment.NewLine + "toplevelcontrol: " + this.TopLevelControl;
        }
    }
```

**Form1** is just an empty form.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        MessageBox.Show(" this: " + this + " owner: " + this.Owner);
    }
}
```

The `Owner` shown in the message box and the `TopLevelControl` shown in the label are `null` when hosted in WPF, but have a value when hosted in another WinForms application.

## Further Investigation

I guess the problem here is that `.Owner` is of type `Form` and there's no instance of this type in the WPF application.  It's hard to imagine what valid value that property could have in this scenario.  It seems likely, therefore, that I need to get the code changed that's accessing the `.Owner' property in **Form1**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window
  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration" 
>

<my:WindowsFormsHost  Name="MapHost" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  SizeChanged="MapHost_SizeChanged" />
```

MapControl inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control

```
MapHost.Child = MapControl;
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- however, I'm already using WindowsFormsHost in my **btnAdd_Click()** method.  I've tried declaring the host control directly in the XAML too, but I still get the problem with the subsequent form opening without an owner.  I'll try to clarify this in my question.

Comment: Okay, I modified my question to put WindowsFormsHost in the XAML instead of instantiating it in **btnAdd_Click()**.  I still get the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @doornail... Did you try setting the Owner???   MyForm.Owner = this (WPF Window);

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because the Form is being created by the WinForms user control, not by the WPF window itself.  I'd like **usercontrol1** to still be able to call `form1.Show(this)`.  When the user control is sitting on a WinForms Form, this works okay (form1's owner is set to that parent form).  When it's on a WPF Window, the owner is `null`.